# In Win32 app the folder selection dialog closes if the folder is not selected and the user clicks OK

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

In my C++ Win 32 application, I am making a dialog to select a folder using IFileOpenDialog for this. Please see the code below:

```
HRESULT DialogService::CreateDialogToPickFolder(HWND hWnd)
{
     IFileOpenDialog* pPickFolderDialog = NULL;
     IShellItem* pPickedFolder = NULL;
     HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPickFolderDialog));

     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
     {
         DWORD dialogOptions;
         hr = pPickFolderDialog->GetOptions(&dialogOptions);
         if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
         {
             hr = pPickFolderDialog->SetOptions(dialogOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
             if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
             {
                 hr = pPickFolderDialog->Show(hWnd);
                 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                 {
                     hr = pPickFolderDialog->GetResult(&pPickedFolder);
                     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                     {
                         PWSTR pszFolderPath = NULL;
                         hr = pPickedFolder->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFolderPath);
                         if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                         {
                             // Some code...
                         }
                     }
                     pPickedFolder->Release();
                 }
             }
         }
         pPickFolderDialog->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}
```

I can’t cope with the following problem. If I do not select a folder (the "Folder" 
field, in the dialog, empty) and click the "Select Folder" button (i.e. OK), the line of code

```
hr = pPickedFolder->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFolderPath);
```

writes
the path that was previously selected into pszFolderPath variable and the dialog closes. But I want
to ensure that, in this case, the dialog remains on the screen and the value of pszFolderPath remains 0x00000000. Because the dialog should be closed only if the folder was really selected by the user, and the name of the selected folder is displayed in the "Folder" field of the dialog box. (Of course, if, to close the dialog, the user clicked the "Select Folder" button. It goes without saying.)
What can I do to prevent the dialog from closing when I click the OK button when the folder is not selected? Help me please.

Comment: Many users don't click OK with selected subfolder. Instead they tend to enter the folder and then click OK - you get path to the folder that is currently displayed (as expected by them).

Comment: On a side note, `pPickedFolder->Release()` is being called whether `pPickFolderDialog->GetResult()` succeeds or fails. It needs to be moved inside the braces above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OnFileOk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogevents-onfileok) event called just before the dialog is about to return with a result. It gives a chance to keep the dialog remain open. If you consider the folder path is invalid return `S_FALSE` to prevent the dialog from closing.

```
    // Create an event handling object, and hook it up to the dialog.
    IFileDialogEvents *pfde = NULL;
    hr = CDialogEventHandler_CreateInstance(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfde));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Hook up the event handler.
        DWORD dwCookie;
        hr = pPickFolderDialog->Advise(pfde, &dwCookie);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {            
            // ...
            hr = pPickFolderDialog->GetOptions(&dialogOptions);
            // ...

            // Unhook the event handler.
            pfd->Unadvise(dwCookie);
        }
        pfde->Release();
    }


// IFileDialogEvents methods
IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk(IFileDialog * pfd) 
{ 
    // If the folder field is empty, return S_FALSE, the dialog should remain open.
    // Check folder is selected or not here.
    //return S_FALSE;

    return S_OK; 
};
```

It may require a parsing operation in `OnFileOk` method to confirm the "Folder:" field is empty or not.

Refer to "[Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776913(v%3Dvs.85)#onfileok)".

**UPDATE:** Add code lines for checking path in the "Folder:" is empty or not. The following is an example using [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) you can refer to.

```
#include <UIAutomation.h>

IUIAutomation *pClientUIA;
IUIAutomationElement *pRootElement;

BOOL IsPathEmpty(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pClientUIA));
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CoCreateInstance error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    hr = pClientUIA->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pRootElement);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("ElementFromHandle error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    BSTR name;
    hr = pRootElement->get_CurrentClassName(&name);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("get_CurrentClassName error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    wprintf(L"Class Name: %s\n", name);


    IUIAutomationCondition *pCondition;
    VARIANT varProp;
    varProp.vt = VT_I4;
    varProp.uintVal = UIA_EditControlTypeId;
    hr = pClientUIA->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, varProp, &pCondition);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    IUIAutomationElementArray *pElementFound;
    hr = pRootElement->FindAll(TreeScope_Descendants, pCondition, &pElementFound);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    int eleCount;
    pElementFound->get_Length(&eleCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < eleCount; i++)
    {
        IUIAutomationElement *pElement;
        hr = pElementFound->GetElement(i, &pElement);
        if (S_OK != hr)
        {
            printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }
        hr = pElement->get_CurrentName(&name);
        if (S_OK != hr)
        {
            printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }
        wprintf(L"Control Name: %s\n", name);
        OutputDebugString(name);

        if (0 == wcscmp(name, L"Folder:"))
        {
            VARIANT varPropText;
            hr = pElement->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId, &varPropText);
            if (S_OK != hr)
            {
                printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                return FALSE;
            }

            if (0 == wcscmp(varPropText.bstrVal, L""))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

The `OnFileOk` method can all `IsPathEmpty` method like this:

```
    // IFileDialogEvents methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk(IFileDialog * pfd)
    { 
        // If the folder field is empty, return S_FALSE, the dialog should remain open.
        // Check folder is selected or not here.
        //return S_FALSE;

        IOleWindow *pWindow;
        HRESULT hr = pfd->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pWindow));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            HWND hwndDialog;
            hr = pWindow->GetWindow(&hwndDialog);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                if (IsPathEmpty(hwndDialog))
                    return S_FALSE;
            }
            pWindow->Release();
        }

        return S_OK; 
    };
```

Comment: Rita, I do: IFACEMETHODIMP DialogEventHandler::OnFileOk(IFileDialog* pfd) { IShellItem *psiResult; HRESULT hr = pfd->GetResult(&psiResult); if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) { SFGAOF attributes; hr = psiResult->GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER, &attributes); if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) { if (attributes & SFGAO_FOLDER) { hr = S_OK; } else { hr = S_FALSE; } } psiResult->Release(); } return hr; }. hr is always S_OK whether folder selected or not. So it doesn't help me.

Comment: @Nupogodi Via UI automation can check if the path is empty or not. I've updated my answer you can try to see if it helps.

Comment: Rita, thank you very much. Everything works as it should. You really helped me. I apologize for the delay in responding.

Comment: @Nupogodi You're welcome. Glad to help. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for helping more people are searching on this issue.